# Searching Access Database based on Textbox choice

Tags: c#

```
private void btnSearchDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection accessConnect = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\ECM\ECM\ECM\ECM.mdb");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ECMeasurements WHERE [Job Number] LIKE " + txtJobNumber.Text, accessConnect);

        da.Fill(dt); 
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;



    }
```

There are also choices that can be searched by Date.....(txtDate.Text) and a comboBox (cbAlloyyTemper.Text). Do I write three different queries or can all the search criteria be together?

Comment: You could write a single `Search(string field, string searchPattern)` function and call that from your form events...

Answer (score 0):

First: **never** use strings in the queries, but use [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx).

Second: I would create 3 different queries, for easy debugging after. But all depends how much queries you can have, and your own comfort feeling.

Comment: And I will only need the three search queries for Job Number, Date and ComboBox...

Comment: @user1487121: there is no much to show actually. 1) you need to understand which query to execute, 2) pick that method and run  query

Comment: My query will display the Job Number if it is only numbers. How do I write a query if my Job Numbers include alphabet characters as well? Here is what I have tried: "SELECT * FROM ECMeasurements WHERE [Job Number] LIKE '%[^0-9]%'" + txtJobNumber.Text.ToString(), accessConnect); Error is - Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[Job Number] LIKE '%[^0-9]%'X12'.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way I would do this at all.

If you are looking at the same table each time you generate each query then you don't want to be querying the database each time. Instead you should load the data into a Data Table, and then query the Data Table in memory rather than the Database each time.

You need to create a Binding Source, and then set the data source for this object to your Data Table object.

For you gridView, you  set the datasource for this object to your Binding Source.

Like so :-

```
OleDbConnection accessConnect = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;       Data Source=C:\ECM\ECM\ECM\ECM.mdb");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ECMeasurements", accessConnect);

da.Fill(dt); 
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

Now, any change in the state of the datatable reflects through to your gridview automatically.

To Query the DataTable you can use a DataView. DataView's allow you to search the Datatable with parameters like an SQL Statment. The syntax is off the top of my head, but its the method that you need to look at.

Look at Querying DataTables, using DataViews. There are many examples on the Internet.

In your scenario, its best suited.

Good Luck.